# How to configure logging for an imported module?

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging, flask, apache-superset

In my [Superset](https://superset.apache.org) web application, I am interested in setting the level of logging in Flask-OAuthLib to `DEBUG`. We can see Flask-OAuthLib access its logger [here on line 26](https://github.com/lepture/flask-oauthlib/blob/master/flask_oauthlib/provider/oauth2.py#L26)
from a Superset web application.

Superset is a web application implemented using [Flask-AppBuilder](https://github.com/dpgaspar/Flask-AppBuilder). It
allows for OAuth2 authentication via Flask-OAuthLib.

I want to configure Flask-OAuthLib logging from `custom_sso_security_manager.py` ... a module described in
[the Superset docs on custom OAuth configuration](https://superset.apache.org/installation.html#custom-oauth2-configuration).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the logger in exactly the same way. They are added to a global dictionary that items can be get from with `getLogger(key)`. So all you need is put something like this into your file after you imported the oauth lib:

```
oauth_logger = logging.getLogger('flask_oauthlib')
oauth_logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

# it is custom for libs to have no handler (except the NullHandler)
# so you may want to add one:
oauth_logger.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler()) # just an example
```

Comment: What if that module and logger have not been instantiated by the source module yet?

Comment: Depends on the library, but if it's not especially badly written it will be no problem. The first call to `getLogger` creates the logger, and as long as the library doesn't set the level of the logger later or removes handlers there won't be a problem.